# Start iexplore from batch with more tabs and inprivate

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, tabs, internet-explorer-10

So I found this vbs script at:
[Post on sof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188850/how-to-launch-multiple-internet-explorer-windows-tabs-from-batch-file/25169091#25169091?newreg=5da4c6f4d10f4dc3bcfa3415a1ef11aa)

The idea is to start IE With more tabs and -inprivate from a batch-file. 
The only thing im missing is that I want the iexplore to start as -inprivate but i dont know where to putt it. I tryed to poste the code her but i got me alot of error.

Answer (score 1):

```
iexplore.exe -private www.google.com
```