# How do I launch two urls into different tabs of the same window in IE?

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer

I'm on IE11, Win 8.1. If I set my default browser as IE, when I launch two URLs from an external program, or by running `Start "http://microsoft.com"` in a PoSh window, I get one window with two tabs.

However, if I manually invoke iexplore like `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.microsoft.com/` then I get two separate windows.

I looked in the registry at how the browser is registered, and believed it would be using the command at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.HTTP\shell\open\command`, however that is set to `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1`.

Passing [`-framemerging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx) appears to have no effect.

So what do I need to do when invoking iexplore.exe to allow it to launch tabs instead of new windows (which is what the Tab settings in IE are set to). I need to be able to do this without IE being the default browser.

Comment: How about launching a local HTML page that opens up the tabs you need?

Comment: I can't, I don't control the first tab, I'm trying to just reuse the IE windows when launching a URL as my users would expect.

(Even if I could though, that's sick... There must be an easy way to do this that Windows is doing, I'm just hoping to find what it is :))

Comment: How about this js/vbs solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25169091/1663001

Comment: I saw that, but I'm really sure there must be a really simple fix, so trying to avoid such madness :(

Comment: From my research I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: I checked with process explorer and it's launching IE like `"IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:10108 CREDAT:275457 /prefetch:2`. Can't even see how it passes the URL. Seems like Windows might be in bed with IE? :-(

Comment: @Evk Already tried the first few answers there, and really didn't want to resort to what's in the VBS sample... Seems crazy that Windows would special-case IE as default when others are just launched and passed the url as an argument? :-(

Comment: Sorry that was wrong link, here is correct one - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3713206/5311735. Still I understand your pain, but maybe that will at least help to solve a problem :)

Comment: The only issue with a solution like that, is that it doesn't take the IE settings into account. I'd like the users settings (to reuse windows/tabs/whatever) to be honoured :(

Comment: Those are stored in registry as I remember, so you can read them there

Comment: Aren't you overriding the users settings my launching a browser that isn't the default?

Comment: @DavidG The user sets my tool as the default browser, and I launch a different browser depending on the url. I want it to behave the same as if those browsers were default, just give a different one based on the domain (see http://blog.dantup.com/2015/09/simple-windows-browser-selector/)

Comment: Wow, someone who still uses ini files!

Comment: @DavidG This is my first time! XML sucks, this seemed like a reasonable format for less technical people :)

Comment: Well it's not wrong to use an ini file, it's just very old and may confuse modern/new programmers who are used to XML. Especially as the code already contians an `app.config` which is so easily read in code and doesn't need 78 lines of code. Anyway if you hate XML so much, why not use JSON? It is so easily read into a class object (1 line of code) :)

Comment: JSON is just as unfriendly to non- technical people. Didn't need to worry about any escaping etc.  I don't mind having extra code of it makes life easier for people using the tool!

Comment: Your users shouldn't use the config file directly if they are not comfortable editing that kind of thing. Let the UI handle it all :)

Comment: @DavidG I have no UI, it was a 1 hr tool. However it makes no sense to say "if the user can't edit a complicated config file that requires knowing XML Encoding or JavaScript string escaping, don't let them have something simple". INI files are fine :P